# How to set into state what the user entered in input?

Tags: search

I have field `searchInput` in my useState(**file Home.js**):

```
const Home = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    searchInput: ""
  });

// THERE SHOULD BE A METHOD/METHODS WHO IMPLEMENT MY TASK 

return (
    <div>
      <Search value={.....} onUpdateSearchInput={......} onSetValue={......}/>  
      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory}/>
   </div>
  );
};
```

Also I have file **Search.js:**

```
export default ({ value, onUpdateSearchInput, onSetValue }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" onUpdateSearchInput={......} value={......}/>
        <button onClick={..........}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### And I have this task:

- When user **entered** into the **search input** some word and press button **Search** this word must be set as a value in field `searchInput`.

**What methods need to be written to implement this?**

**And what I need to be written instead `.......` in all code in both files?**

### Table.js

```
export default (props) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead className="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th onClick={props.changeSortAscDesc}>ID <small>{props.sortAscDesc}</small></th>  
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>CREATED_AT</th>
        <th>UPDATED_AT</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody className="table-body">
       {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id}</td>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
          <td>{item.created_at}</td>
          <td>{item.updated_at}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Comment: creating a fiddle is more helpful than creating a code block. try to give a sample with minimal code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd do. I'll pass the `state` from `Home` to `Search`. Basically, `value` & `onSetValue` & then when `Search` button is called I'll call the parent component `onUpdateSearchInput`.

## Home.js

```js
import React from "react";
import Search from "./Search";
import Table from "./Table";

const Home = () => {
  // use only 1 state for `value` & another state for `listCategory`
  // for easier debugging & better for separation of concerns
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [listCategory, setListCategory] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search
        value={value}
        onUpdateSearchInput={() => {
          console.log(value);
        }}
        onSetValue={value => setValue(value)}
      />
      <Table dataAttribute={listCategory} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

## Search.js

```js
import React from "react";

const Search = ({ value, onUpdateSearchInput, onSetValue }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => onSetValue(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
      />
      <button onClick={() => onUpdateSearchInput(value)}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

## Table.js

```js
import React from "react";

const Table = ({ changeSortAscDesc, sortAscDesc, dataAttribute }) => {
  console.log({ dataAttribute });
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead className="table-head">
        <tr>
          <th onClick={changeSortAscDesc}>
            ID <small>{sortAscDesc}</small>
          </th>
          <th>TITLE</th>
          <th>CREATED_AT</th>
          <th>UPDATED_AT</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="table-body">
        {dataAttribute.map(item => (
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.title}</td>
            <td>{item.created_at}</td>
            <td>{item.updated_at}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

It's okay to do this as it's just 1-level deep. If it gets harder to manage state, you can try using React Context or a state-management library like [MobX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnhIJA64ByY) or [Overmind](https://overmindjs.org)

Comment: 1) How to make that you write:
`() => setValue(value.searchInput)`
in view the method like this:

`const changePage = (argPage) => {    
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      currentPage: argPage,
    }));
  };`
?
Because I can not need setValue in rerurn

Comment: @dok i had 1 minor mistake which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61457555/revisions). i just tried the code in a https://codesandbox.io & it works :)

Comment: In this case error:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/9fea4d230935cf637343d76c8adb26e2/1588008085/19942/1372209/error1.png
I add in answer file Table.js

Comment: @dok `props.dataAttribute` is `undefined` because when you type in the `Search` component, it replaces the input component directly that's why make sure to only use 1 property inside `React.useState` rather than putting your entire apps state. It will make it for easier debugging. In cases where you need to put in entire app state, use a State Management Solution like MobX or Overmind. Anyways here's a short Codesandbox I created for you https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mahavira-t2qd2?file=/src/Home.js